# Does Kafka consumer fetch-min-size (fetch.min.bytes) wait for the mentioned size to get filled?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Suppose there are 107 records, each record is 1kb. If the fetch-size is 15kb, in 7 iterations 105kb would be consumed. Now, only 2kb is remaining, will I get the remaining 2 records in next iterations or will it wait for more 15kb to be accumulated? Assuming after this there are no records remaining after this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It waits until the time defined in `fetch.max.wait.ms` is reached. This value is set to 500 by default. You can find the description of the two relevant configurations in the Kafka documentation on [Consumer](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs)

#### fetch.min.bytes

> The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. If insufficient data is available the request will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request. The default setting of 1 byte means that fetch requests are answered as soon as a single byte of data is available or the fetch request times out waiting for data to arrive. Setting this to something greater than 1 will cause the server to wait for larger amounts of data to accumulate which can improve server throughput a bit at the cost of some additional latency.

#### fetch.max.wait.ms

> The maximum amount of time the server will block before answering the fetch request **if there isn't sufficient data to immediately satisfy the requirement given by fetch.min.bytes**.